# GWT - textbox as search and detect x click event

Tags: java, gwt

I have a textbox where i set the type as a search. So, when you type in the textbox an x appears at the end. As seen in the pic.

[image]

Here is how i am adding it in the GWT

```
firstNameSearch = new TextBox();
firstNameSearch.getElement().setAttribute("type", "search");
```

**Problem:**
How do i get the click event for that x?
I need to be able to do something else besides just clearing the textbox.

This needs to be done with java GWT

Thank you

Comment: That 'x' is likely a browser-specific feature and isn't available for event listening, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a click event for the entire input element, which may or may not include the X icon that the browser provides.  If you don't get the event, listen for click events in an enclosing element.  The trick is working out that the X was clicked rather than the text section of the input.

You could also listen for 'change' events on the input element.  If it previously had contents and you get a change event and now it is clear, it may be due to them clicking the X.